# Can I begin_move_drag only on opaque part when using cairo in Gtk?

Tags: gtk, cairo, vala

Gtk-3.0 here.

I draw some thing directly on window using cairo. Some part of window is transparent, other is opaque(or partly transparent).

I want begin drag (begin_move_drag function) the window **only** when the mouse point is on the non-transparent part. So how can I judge the current point is transparent statu? Get the screen pixmap and check the alpha value? Or maybe some cairo tricks can help me?

Comment: Your code drew the window's content. Can't it just "decide" in the same way which part if transparent? I mean, if you make everything from x=0 to x=30 transparent, then "if (x <= 30)" would do the trick.

Comment: I can not do this test. For some times I just load an SVG picture. other times I use the show_text() method.